# How to understand the Clojure name function?

Tags: clojure

I am confused by Clojure's name function. Its document is:

```
(name x)
Returns the name String of a string, symbol or keyword.

example:
user=>(name :x)
"x"
user=>(name "x")
"x"
user=>(name 'x)
"x"
```

so what is the point of this function? 
where/how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just think of it as a type-cast. You use `name` when you need to ensure you're working with a String data type.

For example turning the map `{:foo 42, :bar "example"}` into the JSON `{"foo":42, "bar":"example"}` requires the use of *name* on the keys, as opposed to *str*, which would produce `{":foo":42, ":bar":"example"}`.